# Compatibility of Drools with web applications

Tags: java, jboss, project, drools

As a final year project i have chosen [this idea to implement](http://elrond.informatik.tu-freiberg.de/papers/WorldComp2012/ICA3340.pdf) A Case Study: Building a Web-Based Dietitian Expert System. 
But In my system there are some other requirements like

1. When user come to site he or she will first make a profile then they are able to use our system
2. Admin can add news related to health
3. Or some other database related activities

But my main functionality is what given in the paper. My question is if i use drools and [Tohu](http://www.jboss.org/tohu) can i make the full web application? like my other requirements can be added easily to the system? I have 2 months to learn the technologies and 4 months to implement.. And if answer is yes then what should be the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools is pure java: it integrates with any java web framework (such as GWT, Errai, JSF, ...) and database frameworks (such as hiberante-JPA, ...).

[Get start on a webapp here.](http://www.jboss.org/developer)

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer..what about JBoss Tohu? should i use it or not? or could you suggest any other alternate of JBoss tohu?

Comment: And also there are many variations in drools like gunover expert etc.. which should i use for my application?

Comment: John, those you mention are tools for authoring rules and a repository to store them. You are not required to use them, but take a look at them and based on what you need decide what to do.